# How can i convert binary to number?

Tags: python, binary, tuples

i made a function like this

```
def integer(n):
    num = int(''.join(n))
    base = 2
    answer = int(num,base)
    return answer
```

and i want to put (1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0) and answer will be 200

but i got error like this

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-70-1c8f3fd15837> in <module>
      5     return answer
      6 
----> 7 integer((1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0))

<ipython-input-70-1c8f3fd15837> in integer(n)
      1 def integer(n):
----> 2     num = int(''.join(n))
      3     base = 2
      4     answer = int(num,base)
      5     return answer

TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, int found
```

what is wrong with my code?

Comment: You can only `join` strings, you need to convert your individual ints to string first. Hint: `map(str, n)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a sequence of string to use  `join` and you can't convert a non-string to int with an explicit base.

```
>>> def integer(n):
...     num = ''.join(str(i) for i in n)
...     base = 2
...     answer = int(num, base)
...     return answer
... 
>>> integer((1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0))
200
```

Answer (score 1):

As @deceze mentioned, the `join` method is only used for strings. If you are passing an array of ints, where each index represents one bit, you can use this:

```
def integerFromBitArray(arrBits):
    iResult = 0
    for bit in arrBits:
        iResult = (iResult << 1) | bit
    return iResult
```